# Was the original super saiyan a golden great ape in canon Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

"When the Dragon Ball Z anime was released, a filler scene in the episode "Goku's New Power" was added showing the Super Saiyan as what looks like a Great Ape with yellowish colored fur instead of the standard brown"

[image]

Later in the non canon Dragon Ball GT we saw a more detailed version of a golden great ape, plus "The GT Perfect Files note that the Golden Great Ape form appears to be the Super Saiyan form from the legends, further implying that the original Super Saiyan utilized the Golden Great Ape form."

[image]

Was the original super saiyan a golden great ape in canon Dragon Ball?

Comment: i think that is a matter of time period!!! during dragon ball Z and GT the golden great ape was the offical legendary super saiyan form but now they probably will change that to fit into the dragon ball super narrative.

Answer (score 3):

Yamoshi was the first Super Saiyan in Dragon Ball. If you recall, way back in the Saiyan Saga, it was stated by Vegeta that it was very common for Saiyans to utilise their great ape transformation to gain an extraordinary amount of power and control the form for combat. Yamoshi obviously utilised the same transformation in Combat and when he attained the Super Saiyan transformation, he was in this state which is why his Super Saiyan transformation seems to be the golden great ape. Goku on the other hand, had his tail cut off and he managed to tap into the transformation without transforming to the great ape. So in other words, Goku managed to attain the amount of battle power necessary in his base form without the great ape transformation which is why his SSJ transformation was possibly different. Yamoshi on the other hand, probably needed the great ape transformation to attain the amount of battle power necessary to turn Super Saiyan.